# Advice for CSS styling of Service Mark Symbol (SM)

Tags: css, stylesheet, html-entities

I need to add the Service Mark Symbol ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service_mark_symbol ) to a bunch of websites.  I have found the XHTML entity code for it ( ℠ ) and have it displayed right now.

The problem is that it is almost impossible to read.  I would like some advice best practices to display this.  Perhaps different CSS is needed based on browser and/or client platform.

I am looking for advice and/or URLs to real-world examples using Service Mark Symbols.

** EDIT **

My problem isn't making the actual SM symbol; the XHTML entity code works.  My problem is that the SM symbol looks bad and is hard to read.

I want some CSS advice and/or URLs for sites that have pretty implementations of the SM symbol.

** SECOND EDIT **

Here is a JSFiddle example of the SM symbol looking bad: http://jsfiddle.net/DGrkd/2/

Comment: This sounds more like a font issue than anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a `span` around the entity code and style that.

**Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/QSR6M/

Note: this does change the line height.

Comment: Thanks, I have done that but didn't tweak the CSS for the span tag too much.

Answer (score 2):

I use this:

```
.superscript {
position: relative;
bottom: 0.5em;
font-size: 0.8em;}

.subscript {
position: relative;
top: 0.3em;
font-size: 0.8em;}
```

HTML code:

```
This is an example of a Service Mark<span class="superscript">SM</span>.<br>
This is an example of a Subscript for the formula for water: H<span class="subscript">2</span>0.
```

Answer (score 1):

Theres the [sup html tags](http://www.htmlcodetutorial.com/_SUB.html)

Comment: It's not clear to me, are you suggesting rather than using the unicode character `℠` he use two ascii chars surrounded by sup tags `<sup>SM</sup>` and it may be more readable?

Comment: Yes. From what I've found you can also use &#8480; although I haven't gotten it to work, possibly because I have utf-8 encodeing